# React-Jest Formio js testing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, formio

I having a react project with formio.js
The problem is like I'm finding it difficult to test the formio pages that are rendered in the react container as a child components.

Eg:

```
<div>
        <Form form={some component} />
    </div>
```

Where div is the parent component or the container and form is the child component rendered inside the div.
The child component is build using the formio json format.

The actual problem is with testing of the child component.

Test code: I'm using jest and enzyme

```
test('child renders correctly', ()=>{
let formwrapper= mount(<Form form={some component} />);

return formwrapper
  .instance
  .createPromise
  .then(formio => {
   const {formHtml} = formio.render();
  Console.log(formHtml);
  expect (formHtml.find(<div class='some class'>)).toBe.true;
   })

})
```

The error is exactly at the .find function: it shows formHtml.find is not a function.

The console.log(formHtml) prints the html inside the form.

What am I doing wrong,
Any references form writing test for formio js will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.